# Haskell zipWith

Tags: haskell, ghci, zipwith

I want to sum a zipped list.

```
averageGrade :: [Float] -> [Int] -> Float
averageGrade [0.75 , 0.25] [6, 4] , result: 0,75*6 + 0.25*4 = 5.5
```

when I go to ghci and do the following:

```
sum(zipWith (*) [0.75, 0.25] [6, 4])
```

I get excactly what i want to.

But in code I'm getting an error, and I don't know why.

```
    averageGrade :: [Float] -> [Int] -> Float
    averageGrade a b
                | a == [] = 0
                | b == [] = 0
                | otherwise = (sum(zipWith (*) a b))
```

If I want to compile this I'm getting the following failure:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Float’
Expected type: [Float]
  Actual type: [Int]
In the third argument of ‘zipWith’, namely ‘b’
In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘(zipWith (*) a b)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't `*` two numbers having a different type, like `Float` and `Int`. You need to explicitly convert one of them so that they have the same type (`Float`, in your case).

```
averageGrade :: [Float] -> [Int] -> Float
averageGrade a b
            | a == [] = 0
            | b == [] = 0
            | otherwise = sum (zipWith (\ x y -> x * fromIntegral y) a b)
```

Note that you do not really need to check the `==[]` cases, since `zipWith` returns `[]` is those cases, and `sum [] == 0`.

```
averageGrade :: [Float] -> [Int] -> Float
averageGrade a b = sum (zipWith (\ x y -> x * fromIntegral y) a b)
```

Comment: I think it's worth adding the reason why the `sum(zipWith (*) [0.75, 0.25] [6, 4])` worked in GHCi - namely that the integer literals `6` and `4` are polymorphic, and GHC is interpreting them as `Float`s (or probably `Double`s, not sure of the default) so the expression typechecks. The problem comes from the type signature, which means you're trying to give two different types to `(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `(*)` different types given that those are members of `Num` type class. You may add `Num` and `Eq` constraints to the type signature such as;

```
averageGrade :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
averageGrade a b | a == [] = 0
                 | b == [] = 0
                 | otherwise = sum $ zipWith (*) a b

*Main> averageGrade [0.75 , 0.25] [6, 4]
5.5
```

However as @chi mentions you don't really need the checks for empty lists hence we don't really need the `Eq` constraint in the type signature. The following should be sufficient.

```
averageGrade :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a
averageGrade a b = sum $ zipWith (*) a b

*Main> averageGrade [0.75 , 0.25] [6, 4]
5.5
```

Comment: Even if the empty list check was necessary, you still don't need an `Eq` constraint. There are better ways to check if a list is empty, like the `null` function or direct pattern matching.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond Yes right. My intention was to fix OP's snippet through the type signature.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative implementation:

```
averageGrade :: [Float] -> [Float] -> Float
averageGrade [] _ = 0
averageGrade _ [] = 0
averageGrade (x:xs) (y:ys) = x * y + (averageGrade xs ys)
```

Usage:

```
averageGrade [1.0, 2.0] [2.0, 2.0]
```